# Facebook share SDK is not working on Mozilla Firefox incognito browser

Tags: php

I am facing issue and having error on incognito browser when i am sharing link through facebook . facebook share dialog is not opening
 . My issue is **Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined**
I tried fbAsyncInit function also in js sdk